# Check multiple files if of the same

Tags: python, os.path

I have a paths_list,assuming they are of the same.

```
In [96]: len(paths_list)
Out[96]: 191
In [97]: paths_list
Out[97]:
['~/Desktop/Dev/sample.py',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.CloudPhotosConfiguration/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.py',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.PressAndHold/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.py',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iCal.CalendarNC/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.py',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.languageassetd/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.py',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.photos.VideoConversionService/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.py',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iCal/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.py',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.share.Video.upload-Youku/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.py',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.py',
 '~/Library/Containers/com.apple.PassKit.PaymentAuthorizationUIExtension/Data/Desktop/Dev/sample.py',
 ...]
```

Tried to check them with a `set`

```
In [99]: { os.stat(i) for i in paths_list}
Out[99]: {os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=8593437981, st_dev=16777220, 
st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=20, st_size=554, st_atime=1510741689, 
st_mtime=1510453338, st_ctime=1510741688)}
```

The returned set contains only one item to conclude that they are some files.

I learn that `os.path.samefile` checking two paths each time.
How to check the paths_list with `os.path.samefile` or other elegant methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am ok with your method, `os.path.samefile()` check `st_ino` and `st_dev` of both files, essentially same with your method, but if your really want to use `samefile()`, try this:

```
all(os.path.samefile(paths_list[i], paths_list[i+1])
    for i in range(len(paths_list)-1))
```

by making sure every neighbor pair of the file in your file list return `True` with `samefile()` call, you could say they are all of the same file.